# How do I use Python's map function with sklearn's preprocessing.scale?

Tags: python, mapreduce, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to use a function (preprocessing.scale) on a list of data. I am new to mapreduce/parallelism in Python - I would like to process this on a large list of data to improve performance.

Example:

```
X = [1,2,3,4]
```

Using the syntax:

```
list(map(preprocessing.scale, X))
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Singleton array array(1.0) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

I think that is because of the return type of the function, but I am not sure how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Python built-in map function has nothing to do with map/reduce parallelism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need/want to use map function as it does `for loop` under the hood.

Almost all `sklearn` methods are vectorized and they accept list-alike objects (lists, numpy arrays, etc.) and this would work much-much faster compared to `map(...)` approach

Demo:

```
In [121]: from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

In [122]: X = [1,2,3,4]

In [123]: scale(X)
Out[123]: array([-1.34164079, -0.4472136 ,  0.4472136 ,  1.34164079])
```

the same demo using numpy array:

```
In [39]: x = np.array(X)

In [40]: x
Out[40]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [41]: scale(x)
DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype int32 was converted to float64 by the scale function.
  warnings.warn(msg, _DataConversionWarning)
Out[41]: array([-1.34164079, -0.4472136 ,  0.4472136 ,  1.34164079])
```

it expects float dtype, so we can easily convert our numpy array to float dtype on the fly:

```
In [42]: scale(x.astype('float64'))
Out[42]: array([-1.34164079, -0.4472136 ,  0.4472136 ,  1.34164079])
```

Comment: This answer would be significantly better if you included an explanation alongside the code.  It's not at all clear that this answer is responsive to the question, because you don't talk about the map function at all.

Comment: @SamHartman, thank you for your comment! I've updated my answer - i hope it got bit clearer...

Comment: @MaxU Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Executing `list(map(preprocessing.scale, X))` is equivalent to executing `[preprocessing.scale(a) for a in X]`.

Given this, what you are currently doing is scaling an singleton (one observation). You cannot scale a single item, and that is where the function breaks. Try doing `preprocessing.scale(X[0])` and you will get the same error.

What is the purpose for you trying to run it like that and not just pass the array X `preprocessing.scale(X)`?